# Can i start my first chord from E major or G major?

Tags: guitar

Can I start my first chord from E major or G major? if I am in a key of c or I must have to start from  C E G . and also to end on it??

Answer (score 2):

You can start on E major and 'cycle of 5ths' your way home to C.

Here's a song that (almost) does that.  It's in F, starts on D7.  But it could have started one further 'fifth' away on A7, which would be the equivalent of a song in C starting on E.

http://www.guitarcats.com/realbook-jazz-standards/sweet-georgia-brown

Or you can forget about being 'functional' and just alternate E major and C major chords.   Nice and floaty.  Maybe doesn't actually 'go anywhere' but so what?

Starting on the dominant chord is incredibly common.  Or on  a ii, V, I.

Honeysuckle Rose for instance.  It doesn't get 'home' (D major) until bar 5.  Preceding it is a few repetitions of Em7, A7  (with decorations).

http://www.traditionalmusic.co.uk/rock-and-pop-songs-with-chords/Honeysuckle_Rose-Fats_Waller_1929.htm

Answer (score 0):

Speaking broadly, most tunes are similar to a journey. Journeys start at a given place (home) and when that journey is completed, you're back home again. So it makes a lot of sense to give the listener a good clue as to what 'home' sounds like, which usually (not always) gets returned to at the end.

Most pieces in C do start with a C chord, and if you started on an E or G chord (presumably to match the note played from the choice of C, E or G), then 'home' would probably come across as key E or key G.

As in my answer to foreyes, to start on a C, there are more choices than just Cmaj., and starting on a G, for example, gives you a choice of G, Gm, C, Cm., Eb or Em for starters!

Or, you may be enquiring with a different viewpoint. The well known and played 'Sweet Georgia Brown' is *in* G, but actually starts *on* E, working its way through the circle of fifths to get to G, so yes, in answer to that bit.